# Can I publish my C++ game on GitHub under MIT using art and libraries under others licenses?

Tags: license-compatibility, mit, creative-commons, github, cc-by-sa

Can I publish my C++ game on GitHub under MIT using art and libraries under others licenses?

I want to publish my code on GitHub, but I have some troubles with licensing.
In my game I use GLEW (Khronos License or Mesa 3-D license), GLFW (zlib/libpng license), GLM (MIT or The Happy Bunny License) and I would like to use art package under Creative Commons CC0 license. It's all distributed under different licenses and I'm doubting.

Can I publish my project under MIT now? What should I do to comply with all copyrights?

Comment: Welcome to the Open Source Stack Exchange! This is a decent first question. One suggestion I would make to improve the chance of people responding to your question is to explicitly state the licenses of  the libraries that your are using. For example, a quick Google search shows the license for GLFW is zlib/libpng (http://www.glfw.org/license.html). Including this information makes it easier for people to answer without spending a large amount of time looking up all of the context around your question. That's just my two cents though.

Comment: @airfishey, Thank you very much! I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and very common.

You can choose any license to cover your own source code, period. But your license does not apply to the libraries and art, since you do not own their copyrights.

If you choose to distribute libraries and art in a package, you need to make sure you are not violating their licenses. But the Knronos/Mesa, zlib/libpng, MIT/Happy Bunny, and CC0 all allow you to distribute them in any way, provided you include their own license texts in the package. I personally include a `LICENSE.txt` for my own source code's license and a `LICENSE-dist.txt` for all the libraries I am including in the distribution. For CC0, you don't even need to do this, but I would do it anyway to avoid questions about their licenses, and because it's ethical to credit them.